# Csrftoken not validating in case of deleting the records in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am learning Yii and i am trying csrf validation
I have made the following class in the **application.components.HttpRequest**

```
class HttpRequest extends CHttpRequest {

    private $_csrfToken;

    public function getCsrfToken() {
        if($this->_csrfToken === NULL) {
            $this->_csrfToken=  sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(),true));

            if(!isset(Yii::app()->session['_tokenforcsrf'])) {
                Yii::app()->session['_tokenforcsrf']=  $this->_csrfToken;
            } else {
                Yii::app()->session['_tokenforcsrf']=  $this->_csrfToken;
            }

            return $this->_csrfToken;
        }
    }

    public function validateCsrfToken($event) {
        if($this->getIsPostRequest()) {
            if(isset(Yii::app()->session['_tokenforcsrf']) && isset($_POST['_tokenforcsrf'])) {
                $sessiontoken=Yii::app()->session['_tokenforcsrf'];
                $posttoken=$_POST['_tokenforcsrf'];

                if($sessiontoken === $posttoken) {
                    $validity=TRUE;
                } else {
                    $validity=FALSE;
                }

            } else {
                $validity=false;
            }

            if($validity==false) {
                throw new CHttpException(400,Yii::t('yii','The CSRF token could not be verified.'));
            }

        }
        parent::validateCsrfToken($event);
    }
}
```

The csrf validation is working properly in case of everything but whenever i try to delete some thing it shows that 
**The CSRF token could not be verified**
Its not validating in case of deletion of the records.

The link from where i am trying to delete is

```
 $this->menu = [
    [
        'label' => 'List Rolearea',
        'url' => ['index']
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Create Rolearea', 
        'url' => ['create']
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Update Rolearea', 
        'url' => [
            'update', 
            'owner'=>$model->roleName
        ]
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Delete Rolearea', 
        'url' => '#', 
        'linkOptions' => [
            'submit' => [
                'delete',
                'id' => $model->roleNo
            ],
            'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?'
        ]
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Manage Rolearea',
        'url' => ['admin']
    ],
];
```

So my question is how can i resolve the issue of csrf validation in this case??

Comment: Is there any particular reson for [reinventing the wheel](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#enableCsrfValidation-detail)?

Comment: the reason is that it uses cookies and i want to learn it with sessions

Comment: But you *do* realise that sessions create cookies as well, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code requires that every action that has been secured via your CSRF token has to be invoked via `POST`. A simple link will result into a `GET` request, which is why your validation fails.

Comment: so how can i do it sir?

Comment: Well, modify your code so it will accept tokens submitted via `GET` as well. [CHttpRequest.getParam()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpRequest#getParam-detail) should help you.